# How can I customize Capistranos SSH command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, freebsd, jail

In order to deploy into FreeBSD jails, I need my commands to look like this:

```
ssh user@example.org "jexec 'web_jail' $THE_COMMAND_HERE"
ssh user@example.org "jexec 'db_jail' $ANOTHER_COMMAND_HERE"
...
```

*Note that, though technically possible, I want to avoid activating SSH in the jails directly!*

So how can I have Capistrano operate like this?

(Note that I am mostly asking in reference to amending the default cap tasks.)

Answer (score 0):

Got chainsaw?

One part that needs clarification is who determines if it is web_jail or db_jail?  Is that the role with _jail appended to it?

The place I would hack into is Capistrano::Command.replace_placeholders.  You could use an alias_method_chain to hook in.  The original is in lib/capistrano/command.rb.

You might be able to do some fancy footwork with the "shell" variable but that would seem pretty hard to do.

Since you have two people watching, this may be a good addition to submit to the Capistrano folks.

Comment: Jails in FreeBSD are named. 'web_jail' and 'db_jail' are those names. They are chosen by the admin upon setting up the jail.